# How to change the default location of stack.yaml on windows?

Tags: windows, haskell, configuration, yaml, haskell-stack

I am trying to install Stack for Haskell on a Windows machine. For the Installation I used the 64bit installer.
After the installer finished I wanted to install stack dependencies with

```
stack install
```

in command line. However, I get this error:

```
Could not parse 'C:\Users\Ren├®\AppData\Roaming\stack\config.yaml':
InvalidYaml (Just (YamlException "Yaml file not found: C:\\Users\\Ren\233\\AppData\\Roaming\\stack\\config.yaml"))
See http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration.html.
```

If I had to guess it is because the default stack.yaml configuration file of stack is stored in AppData which folder name contains my user name. And I guess special characters in this folder name are not supported (since the actual user and the users folder is called "René").

I also allready tried installing Stack in the default location (which is also inside AppData) and a different folder outside of the users folder - still the same problem.

Is there any possibility to change the location where stacks takes its default stack.yaml file from or any other known workaround for this issue?

Comment: Which version are you using of `stack`? Because `stack` changes the codepage of the Windows console to avoid this kind of problem.
Could you run `chcp 65001` before the `stack install` and verify if the problem persists?

Comment: Actually, I just made a test and you are absolutely right. `stack` changes the codepage just to output correctly the GHC messages, as shown by the first message when one runs `stack`:

> Setting codepage to UTF-8 (65001) to ensure correct output from GHC

Comment: `stack --version` returns:
`Version 1.0.2, Git revision fa09a980d8bb3df88b2a9193cd9bf84cc6c419b3 (3084 commits) x86_64`, 
`chcp 65001` also won't help

Comment: Maybe you could change the `STACK_ROOT` system variable as [recommend in their manual](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade.html#windows).

Comment: using `SET STACK_ROOT ...` did not help, but it worked when i set the environment varibale samually in the windows system settings under advanced settings > environment variables

Comment: @RenéMartin: It depends on your shell. CMD will happily accept `SET STACK_ROOT=...`, but forgets the environment variables at the end of your session, PowerShell needs a variable assignment via `$env:STACK_ROOT=...` and also forgets about the assignment as soon as you close it (unless specified in an init script). The environment variable settings is more or less the only "sane" place on Windows to save `STACK_ROOT` in a persistent way.

Answer (score 1):

This was indeed a stack bug, fixed after 1.1.2, and due in the end to a bug in the YAML library (details in https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2491 and https://github.com/snoyberg/yaml/pull/91).